# Microsoft Dataverse : Activites and Notes on Custom Table

Tags: powerapps, dataverse, power-platform

Microsoft Dataverse : Activites and Notes  on Custom Table.

I am unable to add activities on the custom table. I have already enabled option for the table while creating it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbY2T.png)

I want to

1. Allow recoding notes, Phone calls and emails to the custom table
2. I can add existing activities though

Is it possisble on custom table?

1. I have enabled the following options already

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvI75.png)

Answer (score 0):

There's a button "New Activity" in your grid screenshot, it probably does works already?

For notes you also need to check "Enable notes and attachments" in the table properties, then add the "Timeline" component to the form that provides the unified interface for creating notes and other activities.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/model-driven-apps/set-up-timeline-control